# What's the keyboard shortcut to open the "new menu" (PanelUI) in Firefox 29?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-navigation

I am referring to this button:

[image]

(called variously as "new menu" or PanelUI, thanks ciastek!)

Is this basically a mouse-only button and menu, or is there some secret way of using it with the keyboard?

Comment: where is the image ?

Comment: [seems not](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly?redirectlocale=en-US&as=u&redirectslug=Keyboard+shortcuts&utm_source=inproduct)

Comment: @Raystafarian I wouldn't trust that page too much; it lists for example `Ctrl+/` for the now-removed addon bar, and [their page for mouse shortcuts](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/mouse-shortcuts-perform-common-tasks) even lists Alt+Click that [hasn't worked for years](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=713052)!

Comment: @romkyns that's true. I tried every key combo I could think of in FF29 and couldn't get the "new menu" selected.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a keyboard shortcut at all. Even if there was one, you couldn't navigate through the pop-up menu items using e.g. keyboard arrows. I guess it was designed to be mouse/touch only. For what is worth, all items you got (except the options/guide ones) do have a keyboard shortcut assigned.

Comment: "New menu" is called PanelUI. Example bug mentioning this name: [#770135](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=770135)

Comment: From user [goetzc](http://superuser.com/users/294180/goetzc): There is an open bug report to add such shortcut: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1259818

Answer (score 3):

If you put the searchbar in the menu, you can use Ctrl-E or Ctrl-K to open it. That's the best I've found so far.

Comment: In all case you can't navigate by keyboard (arrows or tab) when menu is open.

Comment: The only solution that works even after 2 years